# Define Slicer as Object

Tags: excel, vba

I need help trying to program a slicer to follow either the screen as I scroll or my mouse when I click a cell. This is the code that I have so for

```
Sub Slicer_Test()
'
' Slicer_Test Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+k
'
Dim ShF As Shape
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set ShF = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Academic Career Desc")
       Shape.Range("B1:B132").Select

End Sub
```

it keeps telling me that "   Set ShF = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Academic Career Desc") " is invalid and the object can be found. any suggestions?

Comment: Some info on moving slicer http://www.databison.com/slicer-vba-code-create-change-or-modify-a-pivot-table-slicer-using-vba/  You could try and tie the slicer position to mouse scroll but wouldn't it be easier to just freeze panes by the slicer position so always in view?

Comment: I think the name of your slicer should be ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Academic Career Desc"))

Answer (score 0):

**Declarations:**

I would, if using late binding `Dim as Object` not `As Shape`.

```
Sub Slicer_Test()
'
' Slicer_Test Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+k
'
Dim ShF As Object

Set ShF = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Academic Career Desc")

End Sub
```

For early binding `Dim as Slicer`. You want to be able to access the right associated properties and methods and shape is not correct.

**Syntax wise:**

```
Set ShF = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Academic Career Desc")
```

This seems ok, in fact the presence of the macro name comment indicates you recorded a macro so you have the right object, but why take the risk of ActiveSheet. Be explicit and use the actual worksheet name. What happens if you are not in the sheet you expected to be in? This may well be the culprit.

**Keeping slicer in view:**

I would freeze panes on the view you want so the slicer is always in view. Otheriwse, you are looking at event code and tying the slicer movement e.g. .Increment to mouse/cursor position. That is a bigger piece of work.